# How to solve issue with ExecuteNonQuery in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

This is my code for connection in form.load

```
cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseCasanova.mdb"
cnn.Open()
```

And this is my SQL statement:

```
If ClientNoTextBox.Text <> "" And FirstNameTextBox.Text <> "" And LastNameTextBox.Text <> "" And AddressTextBox.Text <> "" And ContactNumberTextBox.Text <> "" And ProductCodeTextBox.Text <> "" And ProductNameTextBox.Text <> "" And UnitTextBox.Text <> "" And PriceTextBox.Text <> "" And TotalPriceTextBox.Text <> "" Then
        cmdinsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Orders(InvoiceNumber, ClientNo, FirstName, LastName, Address, ContactNumber, ProductCode, ProductName, Unit, Quantity, Price, TotalPrice, [DatePurchase], [DateToDeliver]) VALUES (" & Label4.Text & ", " & ClientNoTextBox.Text & ", '" & FirstNameTextBox.Text & "', '" & LastNameTextBox.Text & "', '" & AddressTextBox.Text & "', " & ContactNumberTextBox.Text & ", " & ProductCodeTextBox.Text & ", '" & ProductNameTextBox.Text & "', '" & UnitTextBox.Text & "', " & PriceTextBox.Text & ", " & TotalPriceTextBox.Text & ", '" & Label2.Text & "', '" & DateToDeliverDateTimePicker.Text & "')"
        cmdinsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("ADDED")
        ProductNameTextBox.Clear()
        PriceTextBox.Clear()
        FirstNameTextBox.Clear()
        TotalPriceTextBox.Clear()
        UnitTextBox.Clear()
        LastNameTextBox.Clear()
        AddressTextBox.Clear()
        ClientNoTextBox.Clear()
        ProductCodeTextBox.Clear()
        QuantityTextBox.Clear()
        ContactNumberTextBox.Clear()
    Else
        MsgBox("Complete your Transaction")
    End If
    cmdinsert.Dispose()
```

I don't know where is the problem because I try 5x to retype the SQL statement.

MS Access is my database and VB10 program

Comment: what is the problem with your code exactly?

Comment: You have to use parameters.  Your sql statement is open to SQL injection.  You have to tell us what the error is.  If this is the "no error, but data isn't saved issue", then that is usually because you are looking at the wrong database, etc.